# WAMP Call to undefined function socket_create() even though enabled in both php.ini files

Tags: php, websocket, wamp, phpwebsocket

I have read numerous posts regarding enabling sockets on WAMP.

I have uncommented the extensions from both php.ini files that exist, and also checked that it is indeed enabled by left clicking wamp icon > PHP > PHP Extensions and making sure that php_sockets is checked ( and it is ).

Also if I view load `phpinfo` in my browser I see that web sockets is enabled.

However, when I try to execute a script from the command line, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function socket_create() in /cygdrive/c/wamp/www/chat/websockets.php on line 20
```

Also, I read somewhere that I should see web sockets in the list if I do the following in the command line: `php -me`, however when I do that I DO NOT see sockets in the list, I guess this might be the problem but don't know what to do about it, since I have enabled everything I found.

Comment: I don't know if that's the case with WAMP but PHP often uses separate configuration files for CLI and Apache. Run `php -i` from the command line and grep for a line saying "Loaded Configuration File" to see what config file is actually used.

Comment: etc/php5/php.ini ,  I am not sure to where that points but in any case I changed both files already as I already said.

Comment: So i changed php.ini files in wamp/bin/php and wamp/bin/apache folders.

Comment: I see you are using cygwin. try running this from a `command window` and not a `cygwin terminal`. You might be running a PHP installed in `cygwin`